# RobotLinking 18B20 pinout and circuit board weirdness

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, temperature-sensor

I have a Dallas Semiconductors 18B20 temperature sensor on a RobotLinking board. It's part of the [RobotLinking 37 Sensors Kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009OVGKTQ). The board has a LED to indicate activity. It resembles this:
[image: sensor that is similar to mine]

Here's what's weird. All the guides I can find for the 18B20 say that the pin order is GND, DQ, V<sub>DD</sub>. That should mean pin 1 goes to GND, pin 2 goes to a GPIO, and pin 3 goes to 3.3V or 5V (this one can take either). Yes, I am looking at the sensor's pins from its bottom.

If I do this, the board's LED is lit solidly. I get 0 degree readings, the same as if no device was connected. (Infinite resistance?)

To make this work, and get valid temperature readings, I have to hook it up this way: sensor GND to the GPIO, sensor DQ to GND, and sensor V<sub>DD</sub> to 5V or 3.3V. The LED only flashes when the temperature is actually read.

Here's a twist: if you look at the circuit traces on the RobotLinking board, it looks like the paths between the male breadboard connectors and the sensor's pins 2 and 3 are reversed. This means if you think you are connecting to pin 3 via the male connectors, you are in fact connecting to pin 2, and vice versa. The path from pin 1 on the sensor to the male pin 1 where it plugs into the breadboard is straight, so pin 1 probably means pin 1.

When I described the above connections I made, I accounted for this apparent circuit pathing weirdness.

Another twist is in the manual, the sensor is soldered to the middle leads. My sensor is instead on the furthest leads from the pins, like in the attached image.

The manual with this kit didn't explain any of this. I'm at a loss to understand my observations. For a generic sensor kit for n00bs, why would one want the pins on the bottom of the circuit board not correspond to the pinout of the sensor?

Comment: Please see http://bigfieldsblog.cloudapp.net/keyes-18b20-temperature-sensor-and-raspberry-pi-2/ for info on how to connect.

Answer (score 1):

From the look of the board, it is designed to support multiple devices. I'd suspect that the three sets of holes give different mappings of the device pins to the board pins. Could it be that the sensor is soldered into the wrong set of holes?

If you have a meter or can see the traces you could look to see if the middle set of holes is wired the way you would expect. If that is a photo of your board, it looks like you have enough length in the leads on the sensor to move it to the middle holes.